# Is there any way to progamatically block quicklook from accessing files to generate thumbnails?

Tags: macos, fuse, quicklook

I have a FUSE file system that accesses remote data. I would like to prevent Quicklook from trying to read the files in order to generate thumbnails because this forces the download off all the files. (The nature of the file system doesn't allow you to just read a chunk of the remote file, the entire file must be downloaded before it can be read.)  Currently I am checking what app is trying to access the files and I block Quicklook by denying it access. I was in hopes that there would be a better way to do this since I am not sure of the side effects of this.

Requiring the user to disable thumbnail generation in the finder is not an option.

Comment: Don't think there's a way to do in FUSE layer. You could maybe create a Quicklook plugin of your own that will block reads (I'm not an expert in Mac).
Windows has the "offline files" mode that solves this, but not Mac.

Comment: Yes, this is one case where Windows got it right.

Comment: An idea - the fuse context holds the calling pid. If the Quicklook is a separate process of it's own (and not a thread inside Finder, for example), you can block it's Fuse calls.

Comment: I already do that. I am just not sure what the results of blocking Quicklook from generating thumbnails might be. I had a report of a site where google drive was installed and they had a crash report in:
 com.google.drivefs.qlgenerator 0x0000000108ef1f0d GenerateThumbnailForURL + 93
It is their bug but I suspect it may be the result of blocking thumbnail generation.

Comment: To get the blocking right I suggest trying as much as different possible error codes to each fs op. These might make a difference in Quicklook behavior.